# Rendering very complicated object in vue js 3 using v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i got a very complicated object from the dictionary API, so im very confused about how to render it using v-for in vue js.
bellow is the object
[image]

my goal is simple, rendering every definition in every meanings in the object using v-for in vue js.
the object structure is like bellow

1. data -> meanings -> definitions -> definition(more than one definition)

**if you have any hints or advice please tell me on comment**

sorry for my incomprehensible english

**THANKYOU IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Looks like you just need 4 nested `v-for`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @TJ 4 nested v-for , okay i will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transform your array instead of trying to render it as is.

```
function transformResponse(response) {
   return response.values().map((item) => {
      return {
          "definitions": item["definitions"].values(),
          "partOfSpeech": item["parOfSpeech"],
          ...
      }
   })
}
```

With that you don't overwhelm yourself with complicated template rendering